# Regarding platform-dependent issue while purchasing space (for domain)

Tags: asp.net, dns

I want to create a Website for that I am using asp.net technology,Since I am Actually Buying a domain and web hosting space for it. Before that I have question regarding some doubts.

I have seen Website http://www.bigrock.in/ . As everyone Knows that Asp.net is platform dependent and I want my Website should open everywhere with same look and feel. And Someone have told me there will be no issue for platform Dependency,You only need to choose Server with windows and deploy Your website there. and after that everybody will be able to open website with same look. Now My question is that if that's the thing is there then why the issue of platform Independent for(java EE,Php) website is there.

Please Clarify my doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ASP.net is platform dependent.

**This is not true.**

An asp.net website can be installed on any web-server provided it has .net framework installed on it. Most modern age windows servers has it. Hence, whoever told you that

> choose Server with windows and deploy Your website there. and after
>   that everybody will be able to open website with same look

Is right.

When somebody accesses your website's page asp.net generates HTML content which is sent to client which is platform independent. Hence all clients will get same look and feel.

Comment: So It means Searching Server For Window appliaction is the Issue (if it is not available easily).Beocz i have learnes about 70% of the server support linux application and rest for windows and other operating system.While The appliaction works perfect in all the operating System.If that is the thing why platform is the major issue?

Comment: Not convinced: you contradict yourself by writing Most modern age **windows** servers -> this is exactly what platform dependence entails. It is platform dependent (windows or Mono) but that is not an issue.

Comment: Sorry I am correcting myself. I have heard that you always need to need about platform Independent thing because it can run everywhere the same.if thats the case and your above all statement are true in your comment. then why Platform Portability issue is there with asp.net based website.

Comment: @Raja: sorry, the comment was meant for Maheep

Answer (score 3):

Platfrom independence in this case is only a concern for the **server**, not the **client**.

A normal asp.net website can be openened in all mainstream browsers, on Mac, Linux or Windows or mobile clients. So it will work everywere.

Comment: So It means Searching Server For Winodow appliaction is the Issue (if it is not available easily).Beocz i have learnes about 70% of the server support linux application and rest for windows and other operating system.While The appliaction works perfect in all the operating System.If that is the thing why platform is the major issue?

Comment: Yes, you need to select a server that matches your programming environment. But if your site is not too big, you can also select a shared hosting provider like Discountasp.net

Comment: my Last Question,Suppose You are Making website like facebook and you are using asp.net and deploying in on windows server.if in the future more members join regularly and you need server to handle more no of people. then the Problem/Issue Of portability Arise.since you wont be able to find windows server.is that Correct?

Comment: If you are going to grow as large as facebook that is the least of your concerns :) Large volumes can also be handled by windows servers...

Comment: I mentioned above that 70% servers support linux. What if you wont get as many as servers to upload for asp.net(i.e window)  based Website easily.

Comment: Both for Windows and for Linux there are **plenty** of options to find and more than enough processing power. It is really not an issue.

Comment: Thanku i was woorying about to choose technology for making my website.now i can concentrate more on developing rather than platform dependent concern.